# Magento 2 : which tables is used for Related Products, Up-Sells, and Cross-Sells?

Tags: magento2, sales-order, related-products, cross-sells, up-sells

I'm trying to get which table saves the Related Products for items and order-items?
Is there any way to know how many items sold by these property.
I try to check this table sales_order_item but I don't find anything?

Answer (score 3):

Currently there is no table which saves the data to check if a products was added through cross-sell or up-sell property.

But for related products, the information is stored in **product_options** column of **sales_order_item** table. You can find **related_product** key in the json of info.

> I don't know why people are downvoting it without specifying reasons. The questions does not ask where the product linking is saved. The question clearly ask if there is a way we can find out if the product added to cart/order was through upsell, cross sell or related product property.

Answer (score 2):

For products the linked products are saved in `catalog_product_link`
The column `catalog_product_link_type` stores whether it's a cross/up/down sell.

You can use the following query to get an overview of the linked product sku's and the relation type

```
SELECT `link`.`link_id` as `link_id`,
`type`.`code` as `link_type`,
`source`.`sku` as `source_sku`,
`target`.`sku` as `target_sku`
FROM `disposable_shop`.`catalog_product_link` as `link`
join `disposable_shop`.`catalog_product_link_type` as type on `link`.`link_type_id` = `type`.`link_type_id`
join `catalog_product_entity` as `source` on `source`.`entity_id` = `link`.`product_id`
join `catalog_product_entity` as `target` on `target`.`entity_id` = `link`.`linked_product_id`;
```

Comment: This is not what the question asks. Question is if there is a way we can identify if a product added to cart/order was through upsell or cross sell or through related product.

Comment: @Afreen Sheikh – yes, in part. The first question is _"which table saves the Related Products"_, so this answer is imo okay. But there is a syntax error, you have to remove the last comma in the field list.

Comment: @digijay Thanks for letting me know. Fixed the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    p1.sku AS product_sku,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p2.sku ORDER BY p2.entity_id SEPARATOR ',') AS related_skus
FROM
    catalog_product_link AS l
    JOIN catalog_product_entity AS p1 ON l.product_id = p1.entity_id
    JOIN catalog_product_entity AS p2 ON l.linked_product_id = p2.entity_id
    JOIN catalog_product_link_type AS lt ON l.link_type_id = lt.link_type_id
WHERE
    lt.code = 'relation'
GROUP BY
    p1.sku;
```

Comment: This is not what the question asks. Question is if there is a way we can identify if a product added to cart/order was through upsell or cross sell or through related product.

Comment: nice answer! thx